# Можно ли в описании метки выставлять ссылки?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, очередь-проверок, описание-метки

Сегодня в описании метки векторного графического редактора [inkscape](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/inkscape/info) внес  ссылку на оф. сайт для скачивания. Но  мои изменения в описании были отклонены...

Но я заново внес правку...

Возник вопрос. Это запрещено?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> P.S.  Просто я видел подобные ссылки, есть в описании метки
>   [sublime-text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/sublime-text/info)

Comment: Не запрещено. Подозреваю, что ваши рецензенты правку отклонили, так как вы ничего кроме ссылки не добавили. Я бы отклонил как "нет описания использования" (имху, более правильная причина). Обычно у вас качественные предложения по меткам, а тут как-то слабо.

Comment: @AK, ок, постараюсь несколько повысить качество своих правок. Но все же данная правка явно описание метки  не ухудшает....

Answer (score 4):

Ссылки могут использоваться, если нужно указать источник информации или материалы для дополнительного чтения по теме. Однако, **только** ссылки на официальный сайт недостаточно для хорошего описания метки. Добавьте хоть какую-то информацию о том, что означает метка и как ее использовать на сайте. Если краткого описания достаточно, забейте и не делайте полного описания вовсе.

Comment: `забейте ` - я как то об этом не подумал....

Comment: -1 Краткое описание может быть полезно и информативно и также может быть лучше, чем никакое. Видел немало удачно раскрывающих суть понятия лаконичных описаний.

Comment: Также было бы хорошо, если бы любую полезную правку принимали, а не отвергали со странным поводом "как-то маловало".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov "Краткое описание может быть полезно и информативно и также может быть лучше, чем никакое" - Может. В данном случае, это не так. SO - не каталог ссылок на сайты графических редакторов.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, если принимать такие короткие описания, то в дальнейшем общее качество описаний может сильно упасть.

Comment: @mymedia У нас нельзя сказать, что очередь из желающих делать описания меток. Многие метки годами не имеют описаний. Поэтому считаю, что пусть каждый вносит описания как может. И если оно хоть как-то добавляет сведений о метке, то я считаю, что это надо принимать, а не ерепениться.